# I reached halfway through a WordPress tutorial to find out I began wrong for a new comer to WP

Tags: pages, templates

Maybe this is not a code specific question, but rather a simple and important question for a new-comer to WordPress. Please guys begging to not downvote it.

So I was following a very good tutorial teaching how to build websites with WP (called themes in WP) **from html**. The mentor takes html pages and converts them into a WordPress theme.

- Let me take as example this code of the blogs page:

[image: blogs page]

The resulting page is as follows:

[image: resulting page]

- All is good so far! So I thought why not try to diverse from the tutorial a bit and try to change the page elements using WordPress Gutenberg or any other builder. But to my confusion, when wanting to edit the page I see it empty!!!!

[image: empty page if I want to edit it with Gutenberg]

I asked a WP developer about this dilemma and if there are many approaches to building a website with WP and his answer was:

"*forget what you learned, and check a tutorial that teach you: wp theme Development because this is what most wordpress developers do, they build on already existent themes or if it's a custom website they use the visual theme builders*"

**This brought me another dilemma. So my questions to WordPress Developers are**:

- What tutorial do you advise to use to build WP themes visually? As I said, I don't want to build from HTML code as I was doing.
- What website builders do you use guys use to build a website with WP?
- I've heard that one can't do everything with the free versions of these builders but has to buy the pro versions, so how can I learn WP theme building in this case? Should I buy a pro version which I might never use after the tutorial?

Comment: So the simple fact is that you've jumped the gun on the tutorial. As far as I can tell the tutorial is teaching you the correct way to build classic-style WordPress themes, which are themes that work just like Twenty Twenty One and earlier. The thing is, that just like those themes, the "Blog" page is not intended to be editable in the editor like that. Before building a theme I would recommend _using_ one of the default "Twenty" themes to get an idea of how they work and what the expected functionality is.

Comment: Modern themes, like Twenty Twenty Two and Twenty Twenty Three are ['block themes'](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/block-theme-overview/), which do allow editing that page (or template), but they work completely differently and you'd need a much more recent tutorial for that. As for using page builder plugins, that's not theme development and not really relevant when you want to discuss "building WordPress themes". It's more relevant when you want to discuss "building WordPress _sites_", particularly without code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructor is correct that you would need to build a custom theme if you want to integrate it better with the WordPress backend. There are two types of themes, which are:

**Classic Themes:** Despite the name they are still modern themes, but they use code more similar to the tutorial you were following and are written mainly in PHP, thus allowing you call specific data from various parts of WordPress to be displayed wherever you want it. They are much more flexible and allow for more fine-grained design than Block themes.

**Block Themes:** Let you create templates that integrate with the Full Site Editor (FSE) that has recently landed in the WordPress core. They mainly use HTML with a few other techniques, but they require you to use the Gutenberg builder to manage all of the content. Essentially the final site is built entirely out of blocks.

There are pros and cons to each but if you want to learn how to create a custom WordPress theme, you would first need to decide which type of theme you want to create and search for tutorials that teach you, or review the official [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/). You can definitely find good free tutorials all over the internet for either type of theme, but purchasing someone's course would probably teach you quicker, as well as offer updates for future best practices and access to the instructor for questions.

Block themes are probably easier to learn how to create, particularly in a visual way, but Classic themes will let you do anything you want to the design.

If you want to avoid coding altogether, you can look into any of the various page builders that work with WordPress with a Google search. I personally like Oxygen but other popular ones include Divi, Elementor, BeaverBuilder, Bricks, Breakdance, and many others with various features and price points. Most of them have a demo or a freemium version you can try, and they all have strong communities - largely in Facebook groups - where you can ask questions.

None of them are as flexible as learning to build a Classic theme, but many of them come close enough that you can definitely build creative sites, and all of these options, including a custom Block theme, would let you create the screenshot you shared.